# UI Automation: How to determine how far a scroll bar scrolls a control

Tags: c#, automated-tests, ui-automation

I'm faced with a problem: I am trying to automate a control with UI Automation. The control is a viewer in a client application, which hooks into a service hosted remotely. As a result of some legacy design decisions, this viewer simply displays a bitmap on a canvas. When interactions occur (e.g. clicks), the position of the click is sent to the service, which uses the co-ordinates to work out where the click occurred, and react correspondingly. The result of this is a nightmare for UI test automation. There is no way of hooking directly into sub-controls, because they are simply painted on to the bitmap. I have found a back-end way of accessing information about what is in this canvas, but now I need to work out where, in this scrolling bitmap, those items appear, so I can interact with them. I use positional information based on the upper part of the control, but since I don't have access to the bounding rects of these sub-controls, as soon as I scroll, all this information becomes invalid. My main problem is that I can't work out how far the scroll bar moves the canvas. Since scroll bars in UIA only have values from 0-100 (despite the actual magnitude of the scrolling effect), I can't work out how far down the canvas I've moved from a known position (it would depend on how far the scroll bar can move at that given time - i.e. how many sub-controls have been rendered in the bitmap). Is there any way of working out the magnitude of the scroll event on this canvas? I know that this must be done internally - the scroll bar has to know how far to move the canvas, based on the actual size of the canvas. However, the bounding rect of the canvas only gives it's visible on-screen position - it doesn't indicate how big the underlying image is. I either need to get the full size of the bitmap (as if it was rendered fully on screen, without scrolling), or to know how much adjusting the scroll value effects the visible position of the image. Is there any way of working this out?